# Parsing a JSON API

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, decode

recently i just try to parse a JSON API and i don't know how it works the list that the json module creates. This is the code;

```
import json

import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/')

print('This is the URL')

print(r.url)

#Json decoding

bitdata = r.text

bitjson = json.loads(bitdata)

print (type(bitjson))
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [Doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), to get JSON response, you need to user `.json()`

```
r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/')
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `load` the `text` manually. Simply `jsonifed_resp = requests.get(URL).json()` would do the trick.